# Extract specific elements from numpy array by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I would like to extract specific elements from a 2d-array by index.
The index specifies the element in the column.

Example:

```
14,  7, 30  
44, 76, 65  
42, 87, 11

indices = (0, 1, 2) or (0, 1, 1)

=> result =  [14,76,11] or [14, 76, 65]
```

I don't want to use any loop, just numpy functions and slicing and stuff.
I thought about masking but again I don't know how to generate a mask-2d-array
from the indices-array without a direct loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row and column index vectors directly:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[14,  7, 30],
              [44, 76, 65],
              [42, 87, 11]])

print A[[0, 1, 2], range(len(A))]
print A[[0, 1, 1], range(len(A))]
```

(Since you want exactly one item per column, the column index vector is `range(len(A))`.)

Output:

```
[14 76 11]
[14 76 65]
```